# Cannot connect css style to login buttons

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I writing ASP.NET MVC app.

I have page with auth from socials.

I found great css styles for buttons.

I make all according to this tutorial [Tutorial](http://www.marknotgeorge.co.uk/possibly-relevant-ramblings/pretty-social-login-buttons-for-asp-net-web-apps-using-identity)

But my buttons don't looks like buttons in tutorial

Here is screenshot:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx1av.png)

Here is my .cshtml file

```
    @model SmartSolutions.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel
@using Microsoft.Owin.Security

<h4>Зайдите используя социальные сети</h4>
<hr />
@{
    var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    if (loginProviders.Count() == 0)
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=403804">this article</a>
                for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
            </p>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           <div id="socialLoginList">
     <div class="btn-group-vertical" aria-label="Login Providers">
           @foreach (AuthenticationDescription p in loginProviders)
           {
            // Use the Caption property to create CSS classes for the button & icon
                string buttonClass = "btn-" + p.Caption.ToLower();
                string faClass = "fa-" + p.Caption.ToLower();

             // The Microsoft Font Awesome icon is 'fa-windows'...
             if (p.Caption.ToLower() == "microsoft")
            {
                 faClass = "fa-windows";
               }

               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg @buttonClass" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" aria-label="@p.Caption" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account.">
                  <i class="fa @faClass"></i>
                     @p.AuthenticationType
                   </button>
          }
       </div>
   </div>
        }
    }
}
```

What I doing wrong?

Thank's for help

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I provide this example.I have code, I tell about problem @DaniSpringer